# Angular 2 ngui-sortable list with *ngFor

Tags: angular, ngfor

I am trying to create a dynamic sortable list 
It work fine when it is static but when i am trying to get it from the base it become  not sortable

this is my static list code

```
<ul ngui-sortable>
    <li >Order</li>
    <li> Me</li>
    <li >Right</li>
    <li id="the">The</li>
    <li id="into">Into</li>
    <li id="put">Put</li>
</ul>
```

and this is what i am trying to do

```
<ul ngui-sortable  >
    <li *ngFor="let menu of menus">{{menu.title}}</li>
</ul>
```

any help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fixed with ng2-dnd  https://github.com/akserg/ng2-dnd
this is my code

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="panel panel-success">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                 Menus
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <ul class="list-group" dnd-sortable-container [sortableData]="menus">
                    <li style="color:blue;" *ngFor="let menu of menus; let i = index" class="list-group-item" dnd-sortable [sortableIndex]="i">{{menu.title}}</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                My prefences:<br/>
                <span *ngFor="let menu of menus; let i = index">{{i + 1}}) {{menu.title}}<br/></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is my component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import {GestionMenu} from "./gestionmenu";
import {GestionMenuService} from "./gestionmenu.service";
import {TreeModel} from "ng2-tree/index";
@Component({
    selector: 'order-menu',
    templateUrl: './order-menu.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./order-menu.component.css']

})
export class OrderMenuComponent implements OnInit  {
    menus: GestionMenu[];
    menu: GestionMenu;

    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private menuService: GestionMenuService) { }


    getMenus(): void {
        this.menuService.getMenus()
            .subscribe(
                menus => this.menus = menus, //Bind to view
                err => {
                    // Log errors if any
                    console.log(err);
                }
            );
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getMenus();
    }
}
```

and finally this is my module

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ...
        DndModule.forRoot()

    ],
    declarations: [
       ...
       OrderMenuComponent,


    ],

    providers: [
        GestionMenuService
    ]

})
export class GestionMenuModule { }
```

Answer (score 2):

The angular *ngFor prevents you from doing such a thing. As long as you are not updating the `menus` array located in the component.ts file, *ngFor will keep rendering in the same order. You will need to fire an event when releasing a `<li>` item so your array's order gets updated.

I suggest you use another library such as [ng2-dnd](https://github.com/akserg/ng2-dnd]). Take a look at the example n°9 which seems to match the desired behavior.